# What is Plausibility of a Megalodon sized creature attacking a human?

Tags: xenobiology, electromagnetism, ocean, sea-creatures, sea-exploration

I have a speculative zoology world with large sea creatures. The astrobiologists don't have a submarine, but they have hi-tech scuba suits. I'm wondering about the reasons for why such large creatures would attack one small potential prey item.

It wouldn't necessarily have to be out of predation. One creature (about 14m + 3m horns) is quite territorial around it's young and would attack anything that comes within it's range. There's even larger creatures (28m, up to 62m) that would still attack the small explorers.

I had the idea of them being irritated by the explorers' magnetic gear. It acting like a dog whistle and the massive sea monsters wanting to get rid of disturbance. Not sure if that's feasible or not.

Comment: The title question is "would x creature attack a human?" but the body seems to suggest that they will attack humans and you are looking for resons why.  If you are asking "would the creatures attack", well, the answer is up to you - they can either be creatures that are cool with humans swimming around or not.  If you want them to attack and are looking for a reason, then define the criteria.  Do you want them to attack all humans all the time?  Do you want to use all humans using x type of device all the time?  Do you want humans to be able to work out how *not* to get attacked?

Comment: Despite numerous report of great white shark attacks, only few are fatal and none are provoked. They are very curious like a toddler putting everything into their mouths but we often forget one minor detail... it's a 4000 pounds toddler.

Comment: Despite Hollywood's imaginative interpretations of megalodons, I wonder if they could even focus on something as small as a human. It would be like a lion or tiger attacking a vole... it's hard to imagine (other than as something to play with, maybe, not that humans in scuba suits would offer much of a challenge).

Comment: However, I do agree with @KerrAvon2055. You're asking one question in your title and a different question in the body of your post. Asking more than one question is literally a reason to close posts. Could you edit your post and pick one of the questions to ask? Be sure to be specific about what your asking and why you're asking it. Cheers.

Comment: It probably should be **"Why would a Megalodon attack a human sized creature"**.

Comment: Adult humans are technically ***megafauna***.  What else is a giant predatory species going to eat?  We are deliciously snack-sized to a Megalodon.

Comment: Blue whales eat plankton.  Just saying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attacks happen for different reasons.

**Food:**

Something has the size, sound, smell and behaviour of prey. Mistakes happen, synthetics smell like seal and groups and sport equipment can sound like something else entirely.

**Territorial defense:**

A area is defended against percieved rivals or predators upon the young of a creature. Especially the last part leads to vicous attacks in the wild, when some walker or climber stumbles upon a den with younglings in the wild.

**Cultural Aspects:**

Some of the smarter creatures, are more then capable of holding a grudge, they are also capable to teach that grudge to there young. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iberian_orca_attacks .

**First Blood:**

It is possible to "attack" first without even noticing it. Cargo Ship propellers, dragnet fishing, oil spills, naval war exercises and loud sonar pings - associated with humans, may change a creatures outlook upon our species. A "Attack" may actually be retribution.

Comment: You forgot fun. "Uh, something shiny swimming around that feels nice. Lets ram it!"

Comment: "Goto fuck with it first, to assert dominance and never even give it a chance to fuck with you!" ..

Answer (score 17):

**Because Humans in the water are really easy to eat**

As a general rule in all manner of combat/hunting/dogfights/racing: Smaller and lighter = more agile.

For a predator, there is a point at which it's not worth the effort. If I have to expend an average of 400 calories to chase/fight an animal because it's smaller and more nimble and it's only giving me 200 calories - that's a net loss.

With Fish, the smaller fish are very nimble and so it's not worth a larger predator *trying* to hunt them because they can dodge and move around to avoid being eaten.

Humans on the other hand, not being a native aquatic animal, don't have the ability to quickly dodge away or avoid a set of chomping jaws - essentially we are a sitting duck.

Now - in terms of Calorific content - according to the Internet we clock in at about 125,000 Calories - A Male Orca (Killer Whale) can burn about 290,000 Calories a day - so we are the equivalent of Breakfast for a Killer Whale.

Apparently the estimates for a Megalodon is around 100,000 Calories per day - which I'm not sure why it's less than a Killer Whale (maybe the Orca is a Mammal?)

But let's for the sake of argument say a Meg needs anywhere between 100,000 to 1,000,000 Calories per day.

Humans are either a full Meal or the equivalent of a Packet of Crisps - and if the effort for the Meg to eat a Human is the same as me going to my Pantry for a Light Snack- just like Me, the apex predator of my Kitchen, staring down a bag of Walkers Salt and Vinegar crisps - a Meg is going to go 'This is easy to hunt, no risk, and a yummy little snack'

Comment: The metabolic difference is the difference between warm-blooded mammal and cold-blooded fish.  The latter might be bigger, but uses much less energy per kilogram.

Comment: There's a chance that you lose a few divers before the big hunter figures out that the hard bits aren't fun to digest and leaves further humans alone, but you'll need a few for it to learn, probably...

Comment: Humans being easy prey might be why even terrestrial predators "develop a taste for human flesh". Humans are kind of slow, really easy to spot, practically blind, deaf and anosmic, and by the time you learn why hunting them is a bad idea you aren't in any shape to teach it to your offspring.

Comment: I think it also depends on the intelligence of the megalodon. For example, for the sharks, we just don't look, don't smell and don't move as their typical prey. We are also very skinny and bony for a shark eating seals. They try to attack and eat us only as a last resort.

Comment: @T.E.D. ["Sharks are a group of elasmobranch fish"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shark)

Comment: @RobWatts - (*reads a bit*) Huh, you're right. Even though they are far less related to other ("bony") fish than humans are, it looks like they are calling both "fish" now. They're even calling lampreys "jawless fish". I guess if you live long enough, everything you learned in school becomes wrong.

Comment: @T.E.D. did they not call sharks fish in ye olden days?

Comment: @Seggan - No. In fact it was a big thing to "correct" people who said they were. "Fish have bones, sharks and rays have cartilage". Kind of like you hear today if someone dares to call a viper a "poisonous snake".

Answer (score 4):

Completely plausible.

There is plenty of sharks that focus on prey not bigger than a single bite for them.

There is no reason a Megalodon-sized creature could not simply move around shallow waters and eat a lot of bite-sized creatures, which for a monster that size means human-sized.

It would not be very energy efficient, hence why it would need to hunt a lot, and be very aggressive and opportunistic (ie: eat anything that moves, ask questions later).

Answer (score 3):

**Because they have a prey species which looks similar to a human swimming in the water.**

In the real world there are many animals which would be physically able to hunt and eat humans but they don't. Attacks on humans are extremely rare, and even then the human is usually not consumed. But these animals have been coexisting with humans for a long time so they had ample time to learn (and they even evolved to "know") that it's not a good idea to try to eat humans, both because we are not that tasty (especially if we wear clothing), and because we are a coordinated species which will then organize and hunt down the animal which killed one of our brethren. Species which did not learn this in time are now extinct.

But a "new" species which just recently started to encounter humans does not know that it's a bad idea to try to eat humans. If there is a similarly sized and shaped species they regularly hunt, then they will consider us prey, and many many generations will need to pass before they will stop doing that.

Answer (score 2):

Since a **Megalodon** and humans never existed for the same time *(at least as far as we know)* it's hard to give a definitive answer. But since this scenario takes place in a **magical world** here are some i ideas i have.

**It is territorial**

As you said your self you have considered this yourself. And i mean why not go with this. Carnivores attack other beings in their territory all the time think animals like **Lions** or **Gorillas**. While i have not heard of any territorial sea creatures i don't see why it shouldn't be possible.

**They see them a threat**

This is in line with them **being irritated** but a little bit different. Animals often attack out of **self defence** like for example **snakes** which often kill humans with their bite even though they can't eat them. And they don't necessarily have to hurt the Megalodon it could just see the way **they act** as a **kind of challenge** and attempt to attack them.

**They look like prey**

Why do sharks in **Real life** attack people? Well it is often that they **look like prey** to them *(though they mostly don't kill them)*. We could just go a step further and say that maybe they are really **prey** to the **Megalodon** like maybe they have some of the **same substance** that there **preferred pray has**. Like their prey might have the same **magical substance** in their body as the **magitech suit** use as fuel.

**Conclusion**

As we have seen there could be many reasons for why a **Megalodon** could attack them. I am certain that i could come up with more especially if you told me more about the **magitech suit**. Which by the way sounds really cool.

*Note: English is not my primary language so please excuse any grammar or spelling errors. Thank you.*